# How to fix a tear between divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a small practice text adventure game project. Lately I have noticed a strange tear that appears between the main story div, and the footer [menu div]. It appears randomly when you scroll the story text all the way down - sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not. The problem occurs both on mobile, and on PC.

**The tear is visible here, right below "Newest line" text:**
[Div tear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEkh4.jpg)

Here an image without the tear, with the text not fully scrolled down:
[No Div tear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL0z0.jpg)

CSS for the two divs:

```
main
{
    font-family: '8bit', Times, serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 32vh;
    padding: 2em;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

footer
{
    font-family: '8bit', Times, serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 30vh;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

I have tried several weird hacks, like CSS transform for both of those - it seemed to help with the tearing, but generated other weird artifacts with the box-shadow and such.

**The full code is available here:**
https://github.com/Akawgan/textRPG

Any ideas what might be causing that, or how to fix it?

Comment: Try giving your footer some `padding-top` and observe where/if the problem appears

Answer (score 1):

I think you have run into the good old "fractional pixel values on a screen with discrete pixels" problem.

The main div has a height of `32vh`, which equates to `509.11px` on my screen, and probably to similar values on different screens.

There's a lot going on between CSS pixel values and the actual size on screen, so without complicating it I'm going to put it this way: some screen sizes can't handle this exact value. Your div is going to be rounded up or down to some integer value, often times "correctly", sometimes "incorrectly".

There's not much you can do to actually fix this issue, short of choosing another height value.

You might be able to work around it by placing the footer `1px` on top of the main element:

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

This is a somewhat dirty trick that just superposes both elements in order to cover any gap caused by fractional pixels.

Comment: Good observation. I was thinking why not having a parent container with a white background and placing the contents of main and footer in there.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I tried that on OP's live version of the site - it didn't work (tried background color on the `.container` element). Do you see any reason why that shouldn't work?

Comment: So I think I figured out the issue. It's the `column-reverse` in the flex direction attribute of `main`. I think the browser initially renders the `p` elements in the order they appear in the html before reversing them. I believe this is the case because when I highlight the text from "Newest line" and expand my highlight downwards, I capture "phantom" text. [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/vqtBMqb). The tear turns out to be the "phantom" text. Also I found the tear to appear when highlighting the text even if the tear didn't appear first.

Comment: I have removed the column reverse and pushed the project - this seems to have fixed tearing completely. 

I have intended to use CSS to reverse the text order instead of JS [the main window HAS to be reversed, to give the game a "booky" feel and auto scroll it to the newest entry] because it looked like a simpler and cleaner way to do so. 

Is the column-reverse just borked like that, or did I use it incorrectly there?

Comment: @Savien I doubt you used it incorrectly. It works as intended. However, that being said, it could be the combination of using the column-reverse and your modifiers on your `last-child` elements of your `main` element causing this phantom phenomenon. I can see your motivation to use column-reverse but it's probably best to utilize JS to alter the order and scroll to the desired `p` because with ARIA based readers, order won't be reversed, [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#accessibility_concerns).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to 'reliably' experience the problem, by gradually changing the width of the viewport. The phenomenon changed, sometimes the background of the container showed through (I changed it to red so it was obvious), sometimes it seemed to be the greeny background that showed through, sometimes it seemed to be neither but instead a couple of gray lines (of different shades).

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is difficult to prove a negative, but if I removed the reverse of the flex column then I never managed to see the phenomenon.

This has to be speculation but it looks likely that putting your text into the order you want it rather than getting CSS to reverse it may remove the problem.

Comment: I confirm - changing it from column-reverse to just column seems to have fixed the tearing issue (at least I can not reproduce it on my devices anymore), tho I'm still puzzled why would it cause artifacts like that in the first place.

Comment: I suspect something is happening in the arithmetic (see @Barthy answer) but why this should be apparent when it's doing a reversal I have no idea - though I can see it's probably having to do a bit more complex calculations. Do you have to use the reverse for some reason or can you get away without?

Comment: I have to reverse the text, to give the story window a more "booky" feel - it would be a mess if new entries appear on top [for obvious reasons, the old entries are still displayed there so when re-reading from top to bottom you'd actually read the story backwards, in chunks] - the CSS reverse was just the "cleanest" option I came across [still learning], other than manipulating it with JS [as the scrollbar needs to automatically scroll to the bottom when a new entry appears]